# Use joomla user table with cakephp

Tags: authentication, cakephp, joomla

i have working joomla project (domain.kz).
and i need to build new independent project on subdomain (newapp.domain.kz)

but i want to use joomla user table. (to let user auth with joomla logins)

- can i declare in user model the joomla jos_users fields
- is it possible to use 2 DB (old one for auth, the new one for new app)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database config in `app/config/database.php`, then create your model as normal:

```
var $joomla_connection = array('driver'      => 'mysql',
                     'persistent'  => false,
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'root',
                     'password'    => 'password!',
                     'database'    => 'joomla_db',
                     'prefix'      => 'jos_'); // I think this is correct

class User extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'User';
    var $useDbConfig = 'joomla_connection';

    //your code here
    //....
}
```

Comment: how to declare the field name in model? if existed field is "user_id" (primary and index) but i need it as "id" field.

Answer (score 0):

you will might experience problems with Auth when you login with the "security_salt" and "cipher" from cake against the user login data, that are created through joomla.

if Joomla saves md5 encrypted passwords you can modify cakestandard encryption with this:
[change hash function - cake cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1254/Change-Hash-Function)